# Why does response.getWriter() throw a checked exception?

Tags: java, servlets

How would an IOException be thrown in below code ? Is it if the response object times out ?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("Test");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: I've never actually seen the exception thrown.

Comment: Remember there's no need for you to catch this exception. `doGet` and its siblings can throw `IOException`, so just let it propagate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write to a socket, so there could be all sorts of IO errors. The socket could have been closed / reset for example.

Answer (score 1):

[getWriter() javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29)

"IOException - if an input or output exception occurred"

In short, getWriter is an input/output operation which tries to open a PrintWriter (I believe). The opening of that writer can simply fail, resulting in the IOException thrown.

Plus, the print() operation is also input/output, so that goes by the same conditions.